# segue using NSCoder in a selected tableview cell

Tags: swift, tableview, nscoder, nstableviewcell

In my swift code code the goal is when a user selects a tableview cell it segues to class Expenset. My code cannot use storyboard only code. You can see in a gif below that my code below is not working.

[gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5FEl.gif)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    @objc func segueAction(_ coder : NSCoder) -> Expenset? {
        
        
        let vc = Expenset (coder: coder)
        
        
        guard let indexPath = tableveiew.indexPathForSelectedRow else {
            return vc
        }
        
        let budget = budgets[indexPath.row]
        vc?.budget = budget
        
        
        tableveiew.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        
        
        
        return vc
        
        
    }


}


class Expenset : ViewController {
    
    
    var budget : Budget?
 private var expenses : [Any] = []
}
```

Comment: Well, as far as I know. You goal is to make sure that when user select that cell then your app shows the expenset vc to user. Am I right?

Comment: How do you call `segueAction`?  If you aren't using a storyboard then segues do not have any application. You would simply present your new view controller from `didSelectRow`.  Also an array of `Any` is not a good idea.

Comment: What's that method `segueAction()` exactly? With a `NSCoder`? If you use segue, it means that you need in your Storyboard to put a Segue between the two ViewController, and put its name. I'd go back to basic and search a tutorial how to use segue and pass data. You should call `performSegue` in `didSelectRow` (or where you want to trigger you action), and pass the data in `prepareForSegue()`.